# Pushing to Github impossible

Tags: git, github, push

I recently created my first gi repository on Github, I cloned it with no problem using carefully http://git-scm.com/documentation. I found no one on the internet having the same issue. I tried 2 different versions of Git : first 1.7.9.5 (from apt-get), then 1.8.1-rc2 (from sources), but finally went back on 1.7.9.5 (from apt-get). I tried by HTTP and SSH (using https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

What I getwhen using push through HTTPS (git 1.7.9.5) :

```
**$ git push https://github.com/Vulpo/PR3003-2012.git master**
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-lsOUEX/pkcs11: No such file or directory
Username for 'https://github.com': Vulpo
Password for 'https://Vulpo@github.com': 
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

and with SSH (git 1.7.9.5) :

```
**$ git push git@github.com:Vulpo/myproject.git master**
Enter passphrase for key '/home/Vulpo/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Counting objects: 19, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 735.94 KiB, done.
Total 18 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Write failed: Connection timed out
Write failed: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

with HTTPS (git 1.8.1-rc2) :

```
**$ git push origin master**
Username for 'https://github.com': Vulpo
Password for 'https://Vulpo@github.com': 
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 736.04 KiB, done.
Total 19 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
Everything up-to-date
```

with SHH (git 1.8.1-rc2) :

```
**$ git push git@github.com:Vulpo/myproject.git master**
Enter passphrase for key '/home/renardc/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 736.04 KiB, done.
Total 19 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
Write failed: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
```

Here is my **git config -l** :

```
user.name=Vulpo
user.email=vulpo@my.mail
core.autocrlf=input
core.safecrlf=true
core.editor=vim
merge.tool=vimdiff
http.postbuffer=524288000
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/Vulpo/myproject.git
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

It seems like no one on the web had this problem before. Anyone has some Idea ?

I tried later (even if I am sure it is NOT because of any github maintenance) and it did not work either. I could push a very light file, but not what I really want to upload (2.3MBytes).

edit : It worked using my broser's computer ! (Git 1.8.0.? on Windows). But it does not resolve my problem. At least, it shows that the problem comes from my own config.

Comment: Haha, wow. That *does* seem really bad. When did you try it? I checked https://status.github.com/ and it seems that there’s some sort of outage at the moment. ("We are currently experiencing major service outages across all services.")

Comment: https://github.com/blog/1363-scheduled-maintenance-windows

Comment: I cloned and tried to push Saturday afternoon (GMT+1), and Github didn't show any maintenance problem to me. Now, I still have the same issue. Is there any website where I can see what is the meaning of each error codes ? I am using Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). I don't know why, but I can't create a new repository now on Github (I don't know why the repository name checking is very long then shows a red warning with no message, even with random name, but this is an other problem). I just tried to push just a file for test, it worked. But it does not work with what I really want to push (2.3MByte).

Comment: Have a look at this, same issue of me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/218728/connection-timeout-when-accessing-github

Answer (score 8):

Well, look what this little guy has got to say.

[image: Github]

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is down. Refer to this site to see what their server status is.
https://status.github.com/