# Cannot push to GitHub

Tags: git, github, connection

First of all, yes, this is an exact duplicate of a [wrongly closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007630/pushing-to-github-impossible).

I have the **exact same problem** as the original poster (and just like him, I haven't been able to find anyone else except him with this problem).

I've been struggling with this problem for over 1 month now, and even had to resort to using bitbucket (which works fine), even though I have a paid plan on GitHub, so bear with me. And no, this has **nothing** to do with maintenance (currently everything is normal on https://status.github.com/, and I still get the same errors as Vulpo did).

Neither my username nor my password contain special characters.

I am also able to push normally using a different computer, so yes, this must have to do **with my computer**. I am running Arch Linux, and here is my `git config -l`:

```
alias.s=status
user.name=Gustavo Machado
user.email=gdmachado@me.com
credential.helper=cache
color.ui=auto
color.branch.current=yellow reverse
color.branch.local=yellow
color.branch.remote=green
color.diff.meta=yellow bold
color.diff.frag=magenta bold
color.diff.old=red bold
color.diff.new=green bold
color.status.added=yellow
color.status.changed=green
color.status.untracked=cyan
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/gdmachado/paradigmas-de-programacao.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Starting a new git folder and pushing just a README file works fine, but as soon as I try to push my files, it simply hangs for a while and then returns an error:

```
-%- src/paradigmas-de-programacao ‹master➔› » git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://gdmachado@github.com': 
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.30 KiB, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
Everything up-to-date
```

Even though it says `everything up-to-date`, nothing has been pushed to the remote server.

SSH also doesn't work. This is the output of `ssh -v git@github.com`:

```
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/gustavo/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/gustavo/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gustavo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/gustavo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-    6+squeeze1+github8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github8 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gustavo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/gustavo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([207.97.227.239]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve gdmachado     c8:d2:c3:fe:b1:81:72:50:9c:ff:fd:c0:88:40:00:4d
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve gdmachado     c8:d2:c3:fe:b1:81:72:50:9c:ff:fd:c0:88:40:00:4d
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
Hi gdmachado! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell     access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2952, received 3000 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6029.5, received 6127.5
debug1: Exit status 1
```

I also get a number of problems when trying to use the github.com website: I also can't create a new repository using the website; the repository name checking takes very long, and after a while a red warning with no message is displayed. Sometimes browsing repos takes forever, and sometimes the main website doesn't even load. If I try to browse the website using a Chrome's incognito window (as in no cookies/cache) it works perfectly for a while(!!!), and after a few minutes stops working again. This is very weird. I can use all other websites (and also push to other git repos hosted in bitbucket for example) normally.

I tried temporarily disabling `iptables`, but that didn't solve anything.

Edit: It works **perfectly fine** on Windows 7. This only happens on Arch Linux :(

So, as I can't reopen that question, does anyone have an idea of what might be going on here, so that we can delete my question and answer Vulpo's? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to attack this problem with low-level analysis? Maybe compare `tcpdump` logs from your computer, and one that is working fine.

Comment: @samuil thanks, that might help, I will try that and update this question accordingly. I also sent GitHub support an email, and if I find any resolution I'll answer this question in case anyone else encounters this same problem

Comment: why are you pushing over https?  have you tried using `git@github.com:gdmachado/paradigmas-de-programacao.git` as your remote url?

Comment: @Eevee yes, unfortunately, pushing over ssh yields another error:
`Write failed: Connection timed out /
Write failed: Broken pipe /
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Please try `ssh -v git@github.com` and update your question with the output.

Comment: Why not just take it up with GitHub support?

Answer (score 0):

You said SSH also doesn't work. However, you have just proven SSH *does* work--at least over port 22.

https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

You got the exact response they were looking for, which was:

> Hi gdmachado! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell     access.

Follow the directions on that link with port 443. If that works, force it as they suggested, and try again.

Comment: I tried following the instructions on that link, and they all worked fine, but when I tried to push to my repo after forcing port 443, ssh push just hangs there forever (has been running for 30 minutes now, with output similar to https, except for the `error:` and `fatal:` lines). Last output line is `Total 9 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)`, with nothing pushed to remote server. It's 1.73KiB worth of data.

Comment: Damn, and I thought we were on to something. Alright, out of curiosity have you tried making another git repository and pushing to that? It'd be odd, but maybe it's just this project.

Comment: Yes! If I create a new one it works fine. But once I add a new file, it bugs out again...